# Deserialising an Enum with a static factory method using Jackson

Tags: enums, jackson, deserialization

How can I deserialize an Enum using a static factory method if I can't change the Enum's source code?

For example, how can Jackson be configured to deserialize using `MyEnum.fromKey()`?

```java
public enum MyEnum {
  FOO("key1"),
  BAR("key2");

  private final String key;

  MyEnum(String key) {
    this.key = key;
  }

  public static final MyEnum fromKey(String key) {
     // lookup by MyEnum.key
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Jackson mixin to provide a `@JsonCreator` that delegates to `MyEnum.fromKey()`:

```java
public enum MyEnumMixIn {
  /* no values */;

  @JsonCreator
  public static MyEnum fromKey(String key) {
    return MyEnum.fromKey(key);
  }
}

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.addMixIn(MyEnum.class, MyEnumMixIn.class);
```